# MySQL update previous record entry when entering new entries

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I ave following MySQL tables

## store_update_stock Table

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| update_stock_id | old_row_id | transfer_status |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|               1 |          0 | Approved        |
|               2 |          0 | Approved        |
|               3 |          1 | Issue           |
|               4 |          2 | Issue           |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

## store_update_stock_details Table

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | unit_price |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+
|                       1 |               1 |  400 |   1 |      10.00 |
|                       2 |               2 |  400 |   2 |      10.00 |
|                       3 |               2 |  401 |   2 |      10.50 |
|                       4 |               2 |  402 |   4 |      11.00 |
|                       5 |               3 |  400 |   2 |      10.00 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+
```

Two tables are joined by update_stock_id. I want to update transfer_status as "Verified", of previous records (In this example, record nos are 1, 2) when inserting new records (In this example, record nos are 3 , 4) of store_update_stock Table. The output should be as follows :

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| update_stock_id | old_row_id | transfer_status |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|               1 |          0 | Verified        |
|               2 |          0 | Verified        |
|               3 |          1 | Issue           |
|               4 |          2 | Issue           |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

My controller as follows :

```
public function verifyItemReqFromHD($id=null)       
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

        $count = count($this->input->post('item_id'));
        $items = $this->input->post('item_id');
        $qts = $this->input->post('qty');           
        $unit_price = $this->input->post('unit_price');         
        $usid = $this->input->post('update_stock_id');

        $total = 0;

        for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
            $details[$x]['update_stock_id'] = null;
            $details[$x]['item'] = $items[$x];
            $details[$x]['qty'] = (-1)*$qts[$x];               
            $details[$x]['unit_price'] = $unit_price[$x];   

        }      

        $stock = array(             
            'old_row_id' => $usid,                
            'transfer_status' => 'Issue'
        );

        if ($this->Item_model->addItemReqFromHD($stock, $details, $id)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Issued..!!');
            redirect('item/approvedItemsToIssue');
        }

    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
        $this->render('item/viewItemtoIssued', $meta, $this->data);
    }
}
```

Model as follows :

```
function addItemReqFromHD($data,$details,$id)
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    if ($this->db->insert('store_update_stock', $data)) {
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        foreach ($details as $detail) {
            $detail['update_stock_id'] = $id;
            $this->db->insert('store_update_stock_details', $detail);
        }
    }       
    $this->db->update('store_update_stock', array('transfer_status' => 'Verified'), array($id => $array['update_stock_id']));

    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;       
}
```

But, didn't get the desired output. Can't understand what I am going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @ Nico Haase. The line, $this->db->update('store_update_stock', array('transfer_status' => 'Verified'), array($id => $array['update_stock_id'])); has the problem

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you verified that this `update` method is called with the proper data?

Comment: @ Nico Haase. Yes. when executing the update As per my model, new records are added correctly to two tables. But the transfer_status of previous record related the old_row_id in store_update_stock table is not working as expected...